# NPM: Getting 403 whoami with npm-automation-token

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm getting 403 for the command npm whoami when I'm using an [npm-automation-token](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-02-npm-automation-tokens/)
This my npmrc:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

When I run the following command:

```
NPM_TOKEN=xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx npm whoami
```

> npm ERR! code E403
> npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/whoami
> npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently npm token for **automation** doesn't support npm whoami [see this issue](https://github.com/npm/feedback/discussions/44#discussioncomment-93588).

For the time being you can generate a token for **publish** instead. I hope this helps future readers.

#### Edit (23 November 2020):

The whoami api is now working with Automation token.